# Is the Laplacian of any test function in $C_0^\infty$ still a test function?

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

As we know, a test function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ function with compact support, and sometimes we denote the family of such functions by $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which is a vector space under pointwise addition and multilication by scalars. Now, if $f$ is a test function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is intriguing to ask whether $\Delta f$, the Laplacian of $f$, is still in $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. For sure, $\Delta f$ must be still infinitely differentiable. How about its support $\mathrm{supp}(\Delta f)$? Is it still bounded and thus compact? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What is the derivative of $f$ in points outside the support?

Comment: You can ask the same question for any partial derivative, not just the Laplacian.

Comment: @Jochen It's zero.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, @Jochen. It occurs to me that
$$\mathrm{supp}(\Delta f)\subseteq\mathrm{supp}(f).$$
Now, since $f$ is supported compactly, one finds that $\Delta f\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: Just by-the-way, for an interesting converse: any linear operator on test functions, without overtly requiring continuity, that does not increase support, is a (linear) differential operator! This is Peetre's theorem. :)